# How to add inputted data into a list without displaying each word as data

Tags: python, list

Can I know how to add inputted data into a list without displaying each word. Here is what I am talking about:
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJdmH.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgx5W.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `getpass` function. If you run this from PyCharm you will need to tick `Emulate terminal in output console` option from `Edit Configurations`. If you run your code directly in a terminal is should work straight away:

```
from getpass import getpass

pass_list = []

password = getpass('Password:')

pass_list.append(password)
print(pass_list)
```

Comment: If it helped, can you please mark it as accepted answer? Thank you!